# Why do I need to refresh the page after logging out?

Tags: php

This is my HTML and PHP:

```
<a href="index.php?logout=true">logout</a>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_unset();
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

this is my JavaScript code to show information whether it's logged in or not:

```
// i call this load function on <body onload="load()">
function load() {
    if (document.getElementById('username').innerHTML === "") {
        document.getElementById('login').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('signup').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('udahlogin').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('udahlogin').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('signup').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And this is my code in header which it will shows the information if it's logged in or not based on my javascript code :

```
<li>
    <a id="udahlogin" onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'"> Selamat datang, <span id="username"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']?></span></a>
</li>
<li id="login">
    <a class="loup" id="login" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"> &#xf08b; Login</a>
</li>
<li id="login">
    <a class="loup" id="signup" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">Sign Up</a>
</li>
```

I already try use onclick event on that element and reload it such as:

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="logout()">logout</a>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function logout(){
    window.location.reload();
    //or
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

But it still need to be refreshed and also in the php too I already use this code before index.php:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

but it shows nothing.

Comment: Put your logout code before you output anything.

Comment: Then enable error reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to redirect via header once you have something printed on document. So this should give you an error if you have it coded as that.

```
<a href="index.php?logout=true">logout</a>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_unset();
        header("location:index.php");
    }
 ?>
```

Try moving that PHP part to the top of your document, before the html tag

Answer (score 0):

The session of the page is decided before the page has loaded. You should either:

1. Log the user out before the session is called again

or

2. Log the user out and then refresh or redirect

For example, for option 2 you might create `logout.php` that logs the user out, then redirects them to `index.php`.

Comment: i got no idea about your first option but for the second option, i've redirect to logout.php that contain session_unset(),session_destroy(), and header("location:index.php") but it still not work, i also put session start at the beggining of index.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. It is simple and all you have to do is drop this at the end of your existing PHP code:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
```

Comment: i've put it after `header("location:index.php")` but it keep refreshing till the end, but it works. How to make it only refreshed 1 time?

Comment: Put this at the end of your the PHP method you call last.